# extracting numbers with decimals and spaces in R

Tags: r

Was wondering if someone could help me solve this. I have this data below.

```
[1] "Compared with 3 months earlier . . . . . . . . 123 (100.0) 11 (8 .9 60 (48. 8) 48 (39.0) 4 (3.3) . . . . . . . . . . . . . ."       
[2] "Compared with 3 months earlier . . . . . . . . 124 ( 100.0) 18 (14. 5) 60 (48.4) 42 (33 .9) 4 (3. 2) . . . . . . . . . . . . . ."   
[3] "Compared with 3 months earlier . . . . . . . . 124 (100.0) 7 (5.6) 42 (33.9) 64 (51.6) 11 (8.9) . . . . . . . . . . . . . ."
```

Would like to extract the above to be something like this

```
123 100.0 11 8.9 60 48.8 48 39.0 4 3.3 
124 100.0 18 14.5 60 48.4 42 33.9 4 3.2
124 100.0 7 5.6 42 33.9 64 51.6 11 8.9
```

There are some random spaces between a number and a decimal which should be treated as a separate number. I have tried to use `str_extract_all()` but it doesn't give me the intended result.

Comment: What did you try with `str_extract_all()` and where is this output actually coming from? i.e. does it have the `[1]`, `[2]`, `[3]` or is this just the output from an R vector? Output from `dput(variablename)` is preferred over cut/paste from `head`, `tail` or `print`.

Comment: str_extract_all(mytext, "[0-9]+"). Was wondering if there is a quick fix. The above is the output from R.  mytext is a character vector which is the output above.

Comment: How were you expecting that to grab the decimals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar approach like @hrbrmstr. Taking hrbrmstr's sample (mytext), I did the following. The `gsub()` part handles the space issue you have. `.(space)` or `(space).` is replaced with `.` in the code. Then, `stri_extract_all()` extracts all numbers. In your case, you have numbers for months, which are the first number in each vector. `lapply(function(x){x[-1]})` removes the first number in each vector.

```
library(stringi)
library(magrittr)

gsub(pattern = "\\.\\s|\\s\\.", replacement = "\\.", x = mytext) %>%
stri_extract_all(regex = "\\d+\\.\\d+|\\d+") %>%
lapply(function(x){x[-1]})


#[[1]]
#[1] "123"   "100.0" "11"    "8.9"   "60"    "48.8"  "48"    "39.0"  "4"     "3.3"  

#[[2]]
#[1] "124"   "100.0" "18"    "14.5"  "60"    "48.4"  "42"    "33.9"  "4"     "3.2"  

#[[3]]
#[1] "124"   "100.0" "7"     "5.6"   "42"    "33.9"  "64"    "51.6"  "11"    "8.9"
```

Comment: @qfd Pleasure to help you. :)

Answer (score 5):

Some tactical character replacement prior to regex extraction is in order and I tend to "think" in `stringi` for vectorized replacements over `stringr` (even though `stringr` has basic support for vectorized replacements and actually uses `stringi` under the covers):

```
library(stringi)

mytext <- c("Compared with 3 months earlier . . . . . . . . 123 (100.0) 11 (8 .9 60 (48. 8) 48 (39.0) 4 (3.3) . . . . . . . . . . . . . .",
            "Compared with 3 months earlier . . . . . . . . 124 ( 100.0) 18 (14. 5) 60 (48.4) 42 (33 .9) 4 (3. 2) . . . . . . . . . . . . . .",
            "Compared with 3 months earlier . . . . . . . . 124 (100.0) 7 (5.6) 42 (33.9) 64 (51.6) 11 (8.9) . . . . . . . . . . . . . .")

# vectorized cleanup

cleaned_text <- stri_replace_all_regex(mytext, 
                                       c(" \\.", "\\. ([:digit:])", "Compared with [[:digit:]]+ "),
                                       c("", "\\.\\1", ""), 
                                       FALSE)

stri_extract_all_regex(cleaned_text, "[[:digit:]][[:digit:]\\.]*")

## [[1]]
##  [1] "123"   "100.0" "11"    "89"    "60"    "48.1"  "48"    "39.0"  "4"     "3.3"  
## 
## [[2]]
##  [1] "124"   "100.0" "18"    "14.1"  "60"    "48.4"  "42"    "339"   "4"     "3.1"  
## 
## [[3]]
##  [1] "124"   "100.0" "7"     "5.6"   "42"    "33.9"  "64"    "51.6"  "11"    "8.9"
```

Hopefully you can do the `as.numeric()` and any other reshaping/conversions.

Comment: Thanks soo much ! Excellent. Works beautifully.